# Compute Shader analysis support in PIX from DX SDK February 2010

Tags: debugging, directx, analysis, directx-11, compute-shader

[DirectX SDK Febuary 2010 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2c7da5fb-ffbb-4af6-8c66-651cbd28ca15) has information about new features, including improvements in PIX with support of compute shaders analysis:

> PIX has much-improved support for
>   analysis of programs that use Direct3D
>   11 features, including compute
>   shaders, tessellation, and dynamic
>   shader class linkage.

I was interested about compute shader analysis and debugging in PIX, so I've downloaded and installed new version of DX SDK. But I was very confused when I was not able to find any particular details about PIX support for Compute Shaders in its' documentation. I've also tried to investigate PIX and find something related to compute shaders in the UI, but I didn't find anything... Could you please point me at the place in documentation or internet, where I can read about compute shaders analysis in PIX or describe how to use PIX to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an [answer from Microsoft on XNA Forums](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/47674.aspx):

> Previous versions of PIX would halt
>   when they ran across any API calls
>   related to compute shaders,
>   tessellation, and dynamic shader class
>   linkage.  This has been remedied in
>   the February 2010 version of PIX.  You
>   can now capture frame data, view the
>   HLSL/disassembly for shaders, examine
>   UAVs/buffers, step through calls, etc.
>   for programs using these APIs.
>
> PIX does not currently have the
>   ability to debug a compute shader,
>   i.e., step through calls, examine
>   variables/registers, etc.  We
>   recognize that this functionality
>   would be very useful, and we are
>   investigating solutions for a future
>   release of the DXSDK.  Nothing is
>   ready to show or announce at this
>   time.